# Wikimedia API query getting cached and inconsistent

Tags: caching, mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

After doing some queries with Wikimedia API, I am not getting any result, all requests seems like cached or not proper.

The [**SandBox API request**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&list=recentchanges&rcstart=2017-01-01T15%3A44%3A21.000Z&rcnamespace=2%7C3&rcprop=title%7Cids%7Cuser%7Ctimestamp&rclimit=20) was giving some response for me yesterday, but today afetr trying other queries I am not getting proper response for any of the query.

So **is there a limit of query we can make from one IP** or if all my requests are getting cached **how to remove the cache**.

Comment: Could you explain what query exactly are you making and what is the response you're getting?

Comment: The link in the SandBox API request , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&list=recentchanges&rcstart=2017-01-01T15%3A44%3A21.000Z&rcnamespace=2%7C3&rcprop=title%7Cids%7Cuser%7Ctimestamp&rclimit=20

Comment: @svick I am getting empty array `"query": {
        "recentchanges": []
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent changes are stored for 30 days of Wikimedia projects (the MediaWiki default is 90). You're requesting data older than that. Did you maybe intend to get changes newer than your date? In that case, you need to specify `rcdir=newer`.